# Does Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 support Configuration Profiles?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering if anyone knew of any built-in functionality, or even extension-based functionality in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 that allowed the user to have different extensions/configurations/window layouts based on a specific "profile"? (Ideally, I'd like to specify the profile I want to use in the command line arguments)

At the moment, I'm using Visual Studio for a number of different types of projects, (C#, C++, some ASP.NET) and as a result, I've got a growing collection of different extensions to help me out. The thing is, there are many extensions that I'll never need when doing C++ development, just as there are many I'll never use when doing web development. While I'm probably just being anal, I dislike the notion of having so many extensions loaded that won't see any use.

Anyways, for the past two years I've been starting up Visual Studio 2010, disabling and enabling the extensions I planned to use on a project, and restarting the IDE. This can get a bit tedious when I'm working on multiple projects in a single day, so I'm hoping someone might know of a trick I've overlooked.